# What is the purpose of the I/O pin capacitor on the AVR microcontroller?

Tags: pins, atmega328, hardware

What is the purpose of the capacitor on the I/O pins on the ATmega328 (I imagine it's on other AVR microcontrollers as well)? Is it to reduce noise from other parts of the microcontroller?

[image: i/o pin schematic]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make explicit the implicit parasitic capacitance on the pin.

Comment: So, it's not actually a capacitor, but just drawn in to the schematic to demonstrate that the pin has capacitance?

Comment: Correct. The input is actually the *gate* of a MOSFET. That gate acts *like* a capacitor. So they show it as one in the simplified block diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The pin does not have a capacitor added to the integrated circuit (IC). Rather this capacitor is drawn to show that the input has capacitance that you need to be aware of.

The input drives a MOSFET - and as we know, MOSFETs have some parasitic capacitance.

For more information on parasitic capacitance of MOSFETs see these pages:

- [MOS Transistor parasitic capacitances - OnMyPHD.com](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=mosfet.parasitic)
- [MOSFET Parasitic Capacitance and Its Temperature Characteristic - ROHM](https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/si/s-si/03-s-si/4873)